# Jmeter in distibuted mode

Tags: jmeter

I am running test for **500 users**. I have one Application server and I am running JMeter in **distributed mode** with one master and **5 slaves**.

The scenario is Jmeter is sending **5 requests** to the server at any point of time. However, I need to control only **Login request** where each Login from the slave  has to hit the server in **different intervals**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **start time** of each and every thread in the slave, set the start time such that each slave starts at a different time.
[image: Refer snapshot]
If you set the thread of slave one **start time** as `2016/06/10 15:03:58`
Set the other slaves same thread as `2016/06/10 15:03:60`
This will make each slave hit the server at different time interval.
**OR**
you can play around with startup delay of each slave, this works too.
Hope this helps.